# Как отдельно определить стили для разных ориентаций печатаемых страниц?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Когда пользователь желает распечатать страницу, в зависимости от того какую ориентацию, в открывшемся окне, он выберет (портретная/альбомная), к печатаемой части страницы должны применяться разные стили.

Каким образом это можно реализовать?

P.S. Проект на ReactJS. Для вывода компонентов на печать используется ReactToPrint (https://github.com/gregnb/react-to-print).

Answer (score 0):

Вам  сюда (спецификация): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@page/size

И сюда (ответ на английском SO): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138422/landscape-printing-from-html

Comment: Спасибо. Как раз сейчас применено это решение. Но `size: portrait` печатает страницу только в единственной данной ориентации. В идеале, было бы круто оставить возможность ориентацию менять. И для каждой оной применять отдельные css правила. А-ля бутстрап для принтов

Comment: Так в чем проблема проставить разные стили для разных `size`?